# Open URL in Word with non-default browser via AutoHotKey

Tags: microsoft-word, autohotkey

I want to use Autohotkey to open a web link in word with *Portable Firefox*.

The browser is not the default browser and resides in USB folder.

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class OpusApp")
#w::
  Send +{F10}        ;Simulate Right Mouse Click 
  Send c             ;copy hyperlink
  clipwait
  clipboard = %clipboard%
  Run "Path\to\Browser\FirefoxPortable.exe" %Clipboard%
return
```

It seems to be working for me. Please let me know if there any other smart ways.

Comment: We can certainly help you with the code for your AHK macro, but we're not a script-writing service.  Please edit your post to include what you've got and tried already, and tell us exactly where you're getting stumped.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty efficient.  You could also assign your macro to an extra mouse button if you have one of the mice with extra/assignable buttons on it, or a middle button you could use to just click the link and have it open in FF portable instead of having to navigate and use a hotkey.  Maybe a hotkey is preferred but just an idea.